# How do I execute a function inside a while loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, api, youtube

I'm trying to make a bot that opens a youtube video when it has a certain amount of views
but i don't know how to execute the function

my code:

```
    import webbrowser
    import time
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    import time
    import pafy
    import os
    import sys
    import subprocess
    import youtube_dl
    
    # ignore the million imports
    
    #(999999995, 1000000000)
    def value():
        url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTHLKHL_whs"
        video = pafy.new(url)
        val = video.viewcount
        if val < 99999:
            print(val)
            time.sleep(5)
    value()
    
    
    while True:
         #what do i need to put here to run "value" over and over again?
    
    
    
    else:
        if value > 99999:
            webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTHLKHL_whs')
```

thanks for all the help!

Comment: Are you watching over the same video again and again? And wait until it reaches a certain amount of views to open it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your value method is working then you can rewrite the code like this:

```
import webbrowser
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
# Millions of other imports

def value():
    url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTHLKHL_whs"
    video = pafy.new(url)
    val = video.viewcount
    return val

while True:
    count = value()
    if count > 99999:
        webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTHLKHL_whs')
        break
    else:
        print(val)
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: thanks dude, fxes that part.   but if the number that i put in is above the amount of views it has it gives me the error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\m8\Desktop\ffs\botaim\relodEx2.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(val)
NameError: name 'val' is not defined

Comment: @Massive_M8 could you show me in detail? If you want you can post a in detail question with screenshot and error traceback. I'll try my best to solve

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer the question?

```
def value():
    url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTHLKHL_whs"
    video = pafy.new(url)
    val = video.viewcount
    if val > 99999:
        return val
    
    
while True:
    values = value()
    if values > 99999:
        webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTHLKHL_whs')
        break
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the if statement on L5? The function will return no value if the video has reached 99999+ views already before you start the script.